# Curl: Passing partial parameters from a text file

Tags: curl, input, parameters, credentials

First time Curl use, trying to call an api to add a series of new words, these words will be read from a text file, at the same, need to pass my credentials: username and apiKey, along with one or two more parameters. The only dynamic parameter (or value of) is the `"word"`.
Curl: Need to pass both, static and dynamic parameters to api from a text file.

Have tried passing the `--data "@myFile.txt" "apiurl"`, also tried the `-K` and `-d`

The parameter `"word=xxx"` should be passed to the Curl from **myWords.txt** file.

```
myWords.xt
"word1"
"word2"
"word3"
```

> curl -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
>   --header "Accept:application/json" -d "username=xxxxx&apiKey=xxxxx&dict=xxxxx" "https://api.languagetoolplus.com/v2/words/add"

I get this error

> This end point needs a user id or just that the "word" parameter is empty.

Any idea or direction as to where I'm going wrong ? ... when I run it directly with all parameters inside a single string `-d "xxxdfsdfsdf"` it works fine.

-thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out you can actually pass multiple --data lines, that solved my issue. Thanks !